# Get all combinations from multiple arrays by key

Tags: php, arrays, combinations, permutation

I am working on an issue. 
I want to generate all combinations from multiple arrays. 
My multiple arrays are products, colors, sizes and models.

```
$products = array("prd_type"=> "prd","code"=>58,"stext"=>"Magnum Frame");
$colors = array();
$colors[] = array("prd_type"=> "color","code"=>60,"stext"=>"Pink");
$colors[] = array("prd_type"=> "color","code"=>61,"stext"=>"Red");
$colors[] = array("prd_type"=> "color","code"=>62,"stext"=>"Black");
$sizes = array();
$sizes[] = array("prd_type"=> "size","code"=>70,"stext"=>"M");
$sizes[] = array("prd_type"=> "size","code"=>71,"stext"=>"S");
$sizes[] = array("prd_type"=> "size","code"=>72,"stext"=>"XL");
$models = array();
$models[] = array("prd_type"=> "model","code"=>80,"stext"=>"Xmall");
$models[] = array("prd_type"=> "model","code"=>81,"stext"=>"Xtra");
$models[] = array("prd_type"=> "model","code"=>82,"stext"=>"Xcode");
```

As a result the generated combination arrray as below.

```
$results = array();
$results[] = array("localCode"=>"58","ltext"=>"Magnum Frame");
$results[] = array("localCode"=>"58,60","ltext"=>"Magnum Frame - Pink");
$results[] = array("localCode"=>"58,60,70","ltext"=>"Magnum Frame - Pink - M");
$results[] = array("localCode"=>"58,60,70,80","ltext"=>"Magnum Frame - Pink - M - Xmall");
$results[] = array("localCode"=>"58,61","ltext"=>"Magnum Frame - Red");
$results[] = array("localCode"=>"58,61,70","ltext"=>"Magnum Frame - Red - M");
#...
#etc
$results[] = array("localCode"=>"82","ltext"=>"Xcode")
```

The key of *localCode*, where generated array, have been generated from the *code* key at the attributes.

How can I generate like above result?

Comment: This is not complicated. Use one function to cycle through all the product values. After it adds each value to results, it calls a function to add on each color. That adds a color and calls a function to add on all sizes. Etc... Have you tried anything like that?

Comment: You could do a few nested `foreach` loops

Comment: @kainaw attribute count and attribute position does not same. How should I proceed?

Comment: @DerekBaxter Have you an example?

Comment: @maverabil This is not a "write my code for me" website. This is a "I wrote this code, please help me improve it" website.